# MX record on RHEL 5.7 host

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I am having trouble configuring my mail server. I cannot seem to get the dns entry correct.

Currently I have:
RHEL 5.7 hostname = oraclemail.crpdom01.com with the ip 10.1.1.249

```
A Name oraclemail.crpdom.com------> 10.1.1.249
```

I need an mx record also. Trouble is do i cannot figure out how do do it?

```
mx mx1.oraclemail.crpdom01.com ------> 10.1.1.249
mx oraclemail.crpdom01.com-----> 10.1.1.249
mx mx1.oraclemail.crpdom01.com ------> A name oraclemail.crpdom01.com
mx oraclemail.crpdom01.com ------> oraclemail.crpdom01.com
```

Any ideas on how to configure this?

Comment: what DNS server are you using?

Answer (score 3):

As per RFC 1035, an MX record must be a canonical hostname; no A record or CNAME is allowed.

If the box is to handle mail for the entire crpdom.com domain, the record looks like this:

```
crpdom.com. IN MX 10 oraclemail.crpdom.com.
```

Comment: It will only handle mail for anything on going to oraclemail.crpdom.com not mail for all of crpdom.com

Comment: So: `mx oraclemail.crpdom01.com-----> oraclemail.crpdom01.com`, just like your last row

Comment: I thought an MX record could not point to a A name record?

Comment: The A record would be the IP address for a given name, not the name.  The MX record in this case points at the name.